# How to delete folder containing files and sub folder properly in a MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc, directory

I have a MFC application where I am facing a problem with folder delete. When I am deleting a folder along with all containing files, it shows deleted from application file list but it shows in Windows explorer but remains not-accessible.When I close the application it the folder vanishes from windows explorer. Why is this happening? I have seen `RemoveDirectory()` in the following code is returning zero. But if it is not deleted, then why does it goes away after closing the application. The function is as follows:

```
void SomeClass::DeleteFileFolder(CString filePath)
{
CFileFind finder;
CString strWildcard(filePath);
strWildcard += _T("\\*.*");
CString str = "";

BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile(strWildcard);

while (bWorking)
{
    bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();

    if (finder.IsDots())
    {
        CString sFile = finder.GetFileName();
        if(sFile !="." && sFile !="..")
        {
            CString sFile = finder.GetFileName();
            str = finder.GetFilePath();
            BOOL bDel = DeleteFile(str);
        }
    }
    else if (finder.IsDirectory())
    {
        CString sDir = finder.GetFileName();
        str = finder.GetFilePath();
        if((str !=".") && (str !="..") && (str != ".svn"))
        {
            DeleteFileFolder(str);
            BOOL bDel = RemoveDirectory(str); 
        }           
    }
    else
    {
        CString sFile = finder.GetFileName();
        str = finder.GetFilePath();
        BOOL bDel = DeleteFile(str);
    }
}
BOOL bDel = RemoveDirectory(filePath);
finder.Close();
```

}

Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an open handle to some file/folder that's not closed until termination or perhaps that it's somehow set as the current working folder for the application.

Did you consider using [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead? You're reinventing the wheel.

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT shfo = {
    NULL,
    FO_DELETE,
    path,
    NULL,
    FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION,
    FALSE,
    NULL,
    NULL };

SHFileOperation(&shfo);
```

The "path" variable needs to be doubly null terminated.