# Delete a directory and all of its files using Windows-Shell

Tags: c++, winapi, com, windows-shell

I'm writing a MFC program that can occasionally remove a directory with all of its content. These directories will be located in *%LOCALAPPDATA%\MyApp* so there will be no permission issue (at least I hope).

My first guess was to use CFileFind recursively along with DeleteFile and DeleteDirectory Win32 functions, but a fast look at [RemoveDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-removedirectorya) documentation pointed me to [SHFileOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationa) and finally to [IFileOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation) which, if I have understood, should be the way how a pure Windows Desktop Application has to interact with the file system, so I would exclude the std::filesystem::remove_all solution if possible.

Now, this is surely a problem of mine because I hate COM, but I found this documentation not very clear if not cryptic, so I decided to have a look at the [developer's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-entry) where I got to the [File Operations Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/fileoperations) which surely helps to understand, but not completely because in my case I have to find the files to delete, so I finally got to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-info#enumerating-the-contents-of-a-folder) guide which should contains all the informations I'm looking for.

Now, if I got the situation I have to:

- access the desktop, which is the root of FS;
- get the path to my directory from the desktop;
- perform my operations;

In plain ol' C++:

```
void CWindowsUtilities::RemoveDirectory(HWND parent, CString& directory)
{
    IShellFolder* desktop;
    HRESULT res = SHGetDesktopFolder(&desktop);
    if (SUCCEEDED(res))
    {
        ULONG eaten = 0UL;
        LPITEMIDLIST itemIdList;
        res = desktop->ParseDisplayName(parent, nullptr, directory.GetBuffer(), &eaten, &itemIdList, nullptr);
        if (SUCCEEDED(res))
        {
            IShellFolder* directoryToDelete;
            res = desktop->BindToObject(itemIdList, nullptr, IID_IShellFolder, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&directoryToDelete));
            if (SUCCEEDED(res))
            {
                IEnumIDList* elementsToDelete;
                res = directoryToDelete->EnumObjects(parent, SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN | SHCONTF_CHECKING_FOR_CHILDREN | SHCONTF_FOLDERS | SHCONTF_NAVIGATION_ENUM, &elementsToDelete);
                if (res == S_OK)
                {
                    IFileOperation* fileOp;
                    res = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(FileOperation), nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&fileOp));
                    if (SUCCEEDED(res))
                    {
                        res = fileOp->SetOperationFlags(FOFX_ADDUNDORECORD | FOFX_RECYCLEONDELETE);
                        if (SUCCEEDED(res))
                        {
                           res = fileOp->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&fileOp));
                           if (SUCCEEDED(res))
                           {
                             res = fileOp->DeleteItems(elementsToDelete);
                             if (SUCCEEDED(res))
                             {
                                res = fileOp->PerformOperations();
                             }
                           }
                        }
                    }
                    fileOp->Release();
                }
                directoryToDelete->Release();
            }
            CoTaskMemFree(itemIdList);
        }
        desktop->Release();
    }
}
```

Letting run the code it goes without exceptions, but on DeleteItems I got:

```
E_NOINTERFACE No such interface supported.
```

Trying to understand where my problem can be, I've tried to enumerate the files in the directory using:

```
void CWindowsUtilities::Navigate(IShellFolder* accesso)
{
    IEnumIDListPtr file;
    HRESULT res = accesso->EnumObjects(nullptr, SHCONTF_FOLDERS, &file);
    if (res == S_OK)
    {
        LPITEMIDLIST itemID;
        ULONG fetched;
        while (file->Next(1UL, &itemID, &fetched) == S_OK)
        {
            STRRET nome = { 0 };
            accesso->GetDisplayNameOf(itemID, SHGDN_NORMAL, &nome);
            CoTaskMemFree(itemID);
        }
        file->Release();
     }
}
```

and so I can see that I can navigate the desktop but not the directory I want to delete.
I also tried using SHParseDisplayName instead of desktop->ParseDisplayName but with no success, even if I got a different **itemIdList**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried [std::filesystem::remove_all](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove)?

Comment: @BoP honestly no, I went directly with Windows APIs.

Comment: There's the Windows API (file system level) and the Shell API (IFileOperation and friends). IFileOperation (more complex to use than regular win32 api) is typically useful for showing UI like Explorer, or supporting virtual folders, recycle bin deletion, etc. for example.

Comment: @BoP Like pretty much any abstraction, `std::filesystem` is lossy. You'll only begin to appreciate how much so if you contrast it with a system that has a far superior API (like Windows'). There's nothing inherently wrong with choosing to program against a system API (even if it is the Shell API) if you need features that aren't exposed in `std::filesystem` (such as progress callbacks).

Comment: @IInspectable that's what I was looking for, but they closed the question.

Comment: Clearly, the suggested duplicate didn't address any of the questions asked. Voted to re-open.

Comment: On a side note, using COM gets much easier by using [smart pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?view=msvc-170#smart-pointers-for-com-objects-classic-windows-programming). Lets you get rid of all these manual, error-prone `Release()` and `CoTaskMemFree()` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SHFileOperation` It has been replaced in Windows vista but still works great.

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT SHFileOp, SHDirOp;
ZeroMemory(&SHDirOp, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCT));
SHDirOp.hwnd = NULL;
SHDirOp.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
SHDirOp.pFrom = _T("path to folder");
SHDirOp.pTo = NULL;
SHDirOp.fFlags =
    FOF_MULTIDESTFILES /* | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION */;

//The Copying Function
SHFileOperation(&SHDirOp);
```

If you really want to use the IFileOperator here is how you could use it:

```
BOOL deleteFileOrFolder(LPCWSTR fileOrFolderPath) {
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        //Couldn't initialize COM library - clean up and return
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Couldn't initialize COM library", L"Whoops", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;
    }
    //Initialize the file operation
    IFileOperation* fileOperation;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOperation, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&fileOperation));
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        //Couldn't CoCreateInstance - clean up and return
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Couldn't CoCreateInstance", L"Whoops", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;
    }
    hr = fileOperation->SetOperationFlags(FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOERRORUI);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        //Couldn't add flags - clean up and return
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Couldn't add flags", L"Whoops", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        fileOperation->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;
    }
    IShellItem* fileOrFolderItem = NULL;
    hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(fileOrFolderPath, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&fileOrFolderItem));
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        //Couldn't get file into an item - clean up and return (maybe the file doesn't exist?)
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Couldn't get file into an item", L"Whoops", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        fileOrFolderItem->Release();
        fileOperation->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;
    }
    hr = fileOperation->DeleteItem(fileOrFolderItem, NULL); //The second parameter is if you want to keep track of progress
    fileOrFolderItem->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        //Failed to mark file/folder item for deletion - clean up and return
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to mark file/folder item for deletion", L"Whoops", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        fileOperation->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;
    }
    hr = fileOperation->PerformOperations();
    fileOperation->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        //failed to carry out delete - return
        MessageBox(NULL, L"failed to carry out delete", L"Whoops", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Both methods had already been resolved in SO in the following links respectively:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22226730/1856251

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68736092/1856251

Looking at your code I can see that one of the things you are doing wrong is that as per IFileOperation::DeleteItems documentation it takes a pointer of one of the following: IShellItemArray, IDataObject, IEnumShellItems or IPersistIDList. But you are passing a IEnumIDList pointer.

Comment: I’ll check as soon as I gain access to my pc.

Comment: Am I asking too much if you point me out errors in my attempt? Just to understand.

Comment: I think the main problem with your method is that you are trying about deleting multiple object (I guess you are thinking in a recursive way). And that is why you are using the `IEnumIDList`. If you think about it in a way that you are only deleting one object. The folder. Then you can use the `DeleteItem` in stead of `DeleteItems`. Then you only need to have the `IShellItem` of the folder which you can get with `SHCreateItemFromParsingName`.